Functions which commute with arbitrary unions
Let $A,B$ be sets and $f: \mathcal{P}(A) \to \mathcal{P}(B)$ be a function. What does it mean to say that such a function "commutes with arbitrary unions"? I read this expression in Exercise 1.1, p.11 of the book "Abstract Algebraic Logic", by Font.
I presume it means for that for any $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ we have
$$f(\bigcup X) = \bigcup (f(X)) $$
However I cannot think of any obvious examples. I tried for example with $A = \{a,b\}$ and $B = \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \}$.
Can you think of any intuitive examples of functions which commute with arbitrary unions in the required sense?

Well, the identity function for one (in the case $A=B$).  Or, if we have a fixed map $g:A\to B$, then let $f$ be the induced map on the power sets.

I don't have this book but I think it's much more likely that it means that if $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ is any family of subsets of $A$, then $\bigcup_i f(X_i) = f(\bigcup_i X_i)$, generalising how "commutes with finite unions" means "$f(X \cup Y) = f(X) \cup f(Y)$".

These functions are determined by their outputs from singletons, since $f(S) = f( \bigcup_{x \in S} {x}) = \bigcup_{x \in S}f({x} )$. So to form such $f$, choose any function $g: A \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(B)$ and then define $f$ by $f(S) = \bigcup_{x \in S} g(x)$; and any such $f$ can be defined in this way.

To prove that was actually one of the exercises. It reminds me in some way of the Kleisli extension : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleisli_category Perhaps they are related.

Are you referring to my comment? If so, you have plentiful examples of your class of functions (by choosing any $g$ you like.) So I'm not sure what you are asking for exactly. What kind of answer are you looking for?

@JairTaylor Actually the object of the exercise is to prove that $f$ commuting in the said way is equivalent to their being a function $g$ as you have defined it. But I cannot see why that equivalence holds.

I've added an answer to that question. Please edit the question to reflect what you've just asked, if that's your intention.

I'll just give some hints and let you fill in the details. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all $f: \mathcal{P}(A) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(B)$ obeying the property $f( \bigcup X) = \bigcup_{S \in X} f(S)$ for any $X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ and let $\mathcal{P}(B)^A$ be the set of functions $A \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(B)$.  We define $\rho: \mathcal{P}(B)^A \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ by setting $\rho(g) = f$ where $f(S) = \bigcup_{x \in S} g(x)$.  We can show $\rho$ is a bijection.
First we have to justify the notation by showing $\rho$ does indeed map into $\mathcal{F}$. To show $\rho(g) \in \mathcal{F}$, let $X \subseteq P(A)$ be any family of sets. We want to show that $f( \bigcup X) = \bigcup_{S \in X} f(S)$. We have $f(\bigcup X) = \bigcup_{x \in \bigcup X} g(x) $ and
$\bigcup_{S \in X} f(S) = \bigcup_{S \in X} \bigcup_{x \in S} g(x)$.  Do you see why these are the same?
Then we can show $\rho$ is one-to-one.  Hint, if $\rho(g_1) = \rho(g_2)$, consider $\rho(g_1)(\{x\})$ for any $x \in A$.
To show $\rho$ is surjective, given $f \in \mathcal{F}$ obeying this property, define $g: A \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(B)$ by $g(x) = f(\{x\}).$  Then we show that for any $S \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$, we have $$f(S) = \rho(g)(S)$$ (prove this!) So $f = \rho(g)$.

Your answer has no obvious relation with the question.

@RobArthan See the comments.  I asked OP what the question was actually about, since it was unclear, and they said it was basically to prove this.  They should edit to clarify.
